# Install R in docker image

Tags: python, r, docker, dockerfile

How do I install R version 3.4.0 in my docker image. I've installed python using:

```
RUN yum -y install https://centos6.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm \
  && yum -y install python36u \
  && yum -y install python36u-devel \
  && yum -y install python36u-pip \
  && yum -y install python36u-tkinter.x86_64
```

Similarly I need to install R:

I've specified following things in file so far for R:

```
ENV R_BASE_VERSION 3.4.0
RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("devtools",dependencies=TRUE)' \
    &&Rscript -e 'install.packages("methods",dependencies=TRUE)' \
    &&Rscript -e 'install.packages("jsonlite",dependencies=TRUE)' \
```

Please suggest .I'm new to docker

I think I need to do something like below:

```
ENV R_BASE_VERSION 3.4.1

## Now install R and littler, and create a link for littler in /usr/local/bin
## Also set a default CRAN repo, and make sure littler knows about it too
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -t unstable -y --no-install-recommends \
        littler \
                r-cran-littler \
        r-base=${R_BASE_VERSION}* \
        r-base-dev=${R_BASE_VERSION}* \
        r-recommended=${R_BASE_VERSION}* \
        && echo 'options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cran.rstudio.com/"), download.file.method = "libcurl")' >> /etc/R/Rprofile.site \
        && echo 'source("/etc/R/Rprofile.site")' >> /etc/littler.r \
    && ln -s /usr/share/doc/littler/examples/install.r /usr/local/bin/install.r \
    && ln -s /usr/share/doc/littler/examples/install2.r /usr/local/bin/install2.r \
    && ln -s /usr/share/doc/littler/examples/installGithub.r /usr/local/bin/installGithub.r \
    && ln -s /usr/share/doc/littler/examples/testInstalled.r /usr/local/bin/testInstalled.r \
    && install.r docopt \
    && rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages/ /tmp/*.rds \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

But I do not know what is this litter and all. I just need R to be installed and then i will install required packages as I have specified above.

## Edits : First line in my docker file installs node4.

Comment: Can you specify, which base image you are using?

Comment: It's my own respository (base image installs node js). It will be great if you tell how i do install R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two DockerFile to install Python, R and NodeJS

The first one installs Python 3.4.2, R 3.1.1 and nodejs 4.8.4:

```
From node:4
RUN apt-get update && apt-get remove -y python && apt-get install -y python3 r-base
RUN cp /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

This second one installs Python 3.5.3, R 3.4.1 and nodejs 4.8.4:

```
From r-base:3.4.1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 nodejs
RUN cp /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

Choose the one that best fits your needs.

Comment: alright,so after this i will be done and I need to put that install packages thing right? and no need to specify r version and all?

Comment: @Alexander Fenyo Ok so here is a change, I need to install python 3.6.1 which I have doine already. It's working fine. Only thing is i need to install R.

Comment: Please guide.From node:4
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y r-base . [ doing only this is fine?]

Comment: You do not give sufficient informations for a complete answer.

Comment: I have specified that I have installed python 3.6.1 already; First line is From node:4 ; I just need R. RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y r-base . [ doing only this is fine?]

Comment: @Alexander Fenyo , Thanks!

Comment: `From node:4` and `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y r-base` and "I've installed Python 3.6.1" is not sufficient. Because you do not give your full DockerFile, so you do not say how you've installed Python 3.6.1. If you want a complete answer, give the whole DockerFile(s).

Comment: check this comment. This is what i did to install python 3.6.1 and node 4

Comment: I do not understand how you can use yum in a DockerFile that starts with "FROM node:4". As I said earlier, node:4 is based on apt-get, not yum. And since you have not a line like "RUN apt-get install -y yum" in your DockerFile, it can not work. Please, check that your DockerFile that starts with "FROM node:4" and contains lines like "RUN yum..." really build a working image. It should not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149948/discussion-between-ashag-and-alexandre-fenyo).

Comment: I can not check since you do not give the From line at start of the DockerFile that is used to build the node4:latest image.

Answer (score 2):

If your public base image (the base image of your own image) is really node:4, then it is not yum based but apt-get based to manage packages.

Thus you shoud install R the following way:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y r-base
```

Comment: Ok, so how will the docker file look like: FROM nodejs (first line) ; RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y r-base (second line) ;ENV R_BASE_VERSION 3.4.0
RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("devtools",dependencies=TRUE)' \
    &&Rscript -e 'install.packages("methods",dependencies=TRUE)' \
    &&Rscript -e 'install.packages("jsonlite",dependencies=TRUE)' \. Please check

Comment: Will it look something like above?   ENV thing will come?

Comment: Exactly what I needed.
my base image was `Python3.6` and need `r-base` for installing `r2py`

Answer (score 0):

You should use some R images, like

https://hub.docker.com/_/r-base/

or some oher image in this list

https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=R&starCount=0

Comment: for some reason I need to install. Can you guide me how do i install? As, I'm already using FROM node for node installation and I think i can't use multiple from in dockerfile, so please tell me how do i install R like I installed python.

Comment: What is your base image (first line of DockerFile) ? Because installing R depends on the base image. Nobody can give you an answer without knowing your base image.

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo .  
It's my own respository (base image installs node js). It will be great if you tell how i do install R

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo ; first line installs node4:latest

Comment: thanks a lot for this useless answer. I am building an image that already has a `from other:image`, and I need to add R to that one.